# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... with WHERE or subselection?

Tags: mysql

i am a bit concerned about one of my mysql queries... The following query receives a variable $DB_id... if a row with that primary key already exists the query performs an update.

```
$this->db->query("  INSERT INTO         modules_text 
                                            (   module_id,
                                                module_content,
                                                module_index
                                            )

                        VALUES              (   '{$DB_id}',
                                                '{$content['text']}',
                                                '{$index}'
                                            )

                        ON DUPLICATE KEY
                        UPDATE            module_content    = '{$content['text']}',
                                        module_index      = '{$index}'

                    ");
```

NOW THE THING THAT CONCERNS ME... There is no relation if the affected rows actually belong to the user. I would like to add a where statement to the UPDATE part or first make a subselecion of the rows which are permitted to be affected. SOmething like:

```
[...]
            ON DUPLICATE KEY
            UPDATE            module_content    = '{$content['text']}',
                            module_index      = '{$index}'
            WHERE            module_post_id    = '{$post]}'
```

Is this somehow possible... Until now i didnt find a solution... Any help would be very appreciated... THANKS A LOT!!!!!

Saludos Sacha!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how ON DUPLICATE KEY works. The update portion of the INSERT will only occur if there's a match for the UNIQUE key(s) or PRIMARY key for the table. (i.e.: The UNIQUE/PRIMARY key(s) are effectively the WHERE clause.)

See the full [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for more information.

Comment: I know... But the id's get passed by the client... so a user could try to modify those keys... In my case this is somehow insecure...

Comment: @Bosh - That's not MySQLs fault. If you're directly passing in database IDs from a query string then that's your design flaw. (Why not store a unique textual module reference and use that instead?)

Comment: I know ;-) Because of that design flaw i am looking for a solution ;-) Actually i obfuscate the id's already to make it more secure but its not one of the most strongest algorythms because of performance... What do you mean exactly with unique textual module reference... I googled but didnt find an axplanation... Thank You!

Comment: @Bosh Instead of using an ID, use a text reference (e.g.: "testmodule") and store this reference in the database table along with the ID. As such, instead of having to do a lookup on an ID, you do the lookup on the text name, which unlike an ID can't be easily guessed.

Comment: Hmm... okay i understand... I'll give that a try if i don't find a simpler solution. I am a little bit worried  how this effects performance selecting by textual ids rather than numeric id's... Furthermore I already have the necessary data to make it secure i just need to find the best way to handle it. Adding another column should be the last choice... As you mentioned its a design flaw not a lack of data ;-) So i should first try to modify my queries not the data ;-) Thank you very much...

Comment: @Bosh as long as the module reference field is an index it'll be just as fast. It also means you can create SEO friendly URLs, etc. in the future. :-)

Comment: hehe... I already use textual id's for nicer urls... but till now only for the main table entries and not this part of the application ;-)